# WCF MessageContract List Serialization

Tags: wcf, serialization, soap, messagecontract

I have the following MessageContracts to use as a request:

```
<MessageContract(WrapperName:="get")> _
Public Class GetRequest
    Inherits BaseAuthenticatedRequest

    Protected _typeName As cEnum.eType
    Protected _id As Integer

    <MessageBodyMember()> _
    Public Property TypeName() As cEnum.eType
    ...

    <MessageBodyMember()> _
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    ...
End Class

<MessageContract(WrapperName:="getLimited")> _
Public Class GetLimitedRequest
    Inherits GetRequest

    Protected _propertyList As List(Of String)

    <MessageBodyMember(Namespace:=Api2Information.Namespace)> _
    Public Property PropertyList() As List(Of String)
    ...
End Class
```

But when testing in SoapUI, the getLimited request body is being created as:

```
  <v2:getLimited>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v2:Id>?</v2:Id>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v2:PropertyList>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <arr:string>?</arr:string>
     </v2:PropertyList>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v2:TypeName>?</v2:TypeName>
  </v2:getLimited>
```

Where `v2` = Api2Information.Namespace.  What I really want is for the strings contained within PropertyList to be namespaced as `v2`, not `arr`.  Is there anyway for me to achieve that?  I'm converting an ASMX service to use WCF and we have a few applications where we cannot afford to have to recompile and redistribute.

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: `Api2Information.Namespace` is used on my service methods also, to get everything under the namespace.  Adding a namespace to `PropertyList` didn't change anything, it was just my attempt to get the strings to be namespaced correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.  Using a custom collection type like:

```
<CollectionDataContract(Namespace:=Api2Information.Namespace)> _
Public Class PropertyList : Inherits List(Of String)

End Class
```

and replacing occurrences of it in my contracts like:

```
<MessageContract(WrapperName:="getLimited")> _
Public Class GetLimitedRequest
    Inherits GetRequest

    Protected _propertyList As PropertyList

    <MessageBodyMember(Namespace:=Api2Information.Namespace)> _
    Public Property PropertyList() As PropertyList
    ...
End Class
```

Produces the output:

```
  <v2:getLimited>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v2:Id>?</v2:Id>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v2:PropertyList>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <v2:string>?</v2:string>
     </v2:PropertyList>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v2:TypeName>?</v2:TypeName>
  </v2:getLimited>
```